# How to split a data file for ploting multiple graphs in a 2D diagram

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data file containig different patrs like this:

```
      VL =   1   nthr =   1   L =   33554432   t = 8.198e-02 secs   P =     2.865266 Gflop/s   B =     8.186473 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   2   L =   33554432   t = 4.548e-02 secs   P =     5.164911 Gflop/s   B =    14.756890 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   3   L =   33554432   t = 3.832e-02 secs   P =     6.128806 Gflop/s   B =    17.510875 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   4   L =   33554432   t = 3.626e-02 secs   P =     6.477458 Gflop/s   B =    18.507023 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   5   L =   33554432   t = 3.952e-02 secs   P =     5.943677 Gflop/s   B =    16.981935 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   6   L =   33554432   t = 3.527e-02 secs   P =     6.660278 Gflop/s   B =    19.029367 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   7   L =   33554432   t = 3.382e-02 secs   P =     6.944645 Gflop/s   B =    19.841842 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   8   L =   33554432   t = 3.663e-02 secs   P =     6.412828 Gflop/s   B =    18.322367 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =   9   L =   33554432   t = 3.613e-02 secs   P =     6.500197 Gflop/s   B =    18.571992 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  10   L =   33554432   t = 3.704e-02 secs   P =     6.341716 Gflop/s   B =    18.119188 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  11   L =   33554432   t = 3.518e-02 secs   P =     6.676055 Gflop/s   B =    19.074443 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  12   L =   33554432   t = 3.541e-02 secs   P =     6.633905 Gflop/s   B =    18.954014 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  13   L =   33554432   t = 3.527e-02 secs   P =     6.660107 Gflop/s   B =    19.028878 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  14   L =   33554432   t = 3.519e-02 secs   P =     6.675365 Gflop/s   B =    19.072472 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  15   L =   33554432   t = 3.577e-02 secs   P =     6.565543 Gflop/s   B =    18.758696 Gbytes/s
      VL =   1   nthr =  16   L =   33554432   t = 4.262e-02 secs   P =     5.511646 Gflop/s   B =    15.747561 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   1   L =   33554432   t = 6.682e-02 secs   P =     3.514952 Gflop/s   B =    10.042719 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   2   L =   33554432   t = 4.033e-02 secs   P =     5.823826 Gflop/s   B =    16.639502 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   3   L =   33554432   t = 3.688e-02 secs   P =     6.369283 Gflop/s   B =    18.197950 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   4   L =   33554432   t = 3.499e-02 secs   P =     6.712527 Gflop/s   B =    19.178650 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   5   L =   33554432   t = 3.737e-02 secs   P =     6.285014 Gflop/s   B =    17.957183 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   6   L =   33554432   t = 3.470e-02 secs   P =     6.768417 Gflop/s   B =    19.338335 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   7   L =   33554432   t = 3.428e-02 secs   P =     6.851600 Gflop/s   B =    19.575999 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   8   L =   33554432   t = 3.648e-02 secs   P =     6.437901 Gflop/s   B =    18.394004 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =   9   L =   33554432   t = 3.607e-02 secs   P =     6.512441 Gflop/s   B =    18.606976 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  10   L =   33554432   t = 3.695e-02 secs   P =     6.356346 Gflop/s   B =    18.160988 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  11   L =   33554432   t = 3.559e-02 secs   P =     6.600218 Gflop/s   B =    18.857766 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  12   L =   33554432   t = 3.557e-02 secs   P =     6.603076 Gflop/s   B =    18.865931 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  13   L =   33554432   t = 3.527e-02 secs   P =     6.660324 Gflop/s   B =    19.029496 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  14   L =   33554432   t = 3.546e-02 secs   P =     6.623270 Gflop/s   B =    18.923629 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  15   L =   33554432   t = 3.595e-02 secs   P =     6.534075 Gflop/s   B =    18.668786 Gbytes/s
      VL =   2   nthr =  16   L =   33554432   t = 4.192e-02 secs   P =     5.602932 Gflop/s   B =    16.008377 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   1   L =   33554432   t = 6.287e-02 secs   P =     3.736104 Gflop/s   B =    10.674583 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   2   L =   33554432   t = 3.660e-02 secs   P =     6.417181 Gflop/s   B =    18.334803 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   3   L =   33554432   t = 3.225e-02 secs   P =     7.282963 Gflop/s   B =    20.808466 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   4   L =   33554432   t = 3.130e-02 secs   P =     7.504810 Gflop/s   B =    21.442314 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   5   L =   33554432   t = 3.641e-02 secs   P =     6.450418 Gflop/s   B =    18.429767 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   6   L =   33554432   t = 3.168e-02 secs   P =     7.414581 Gflop/s   B =    21.184517 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   7   L =   33554432   t = 3.175e-02 secs   P =     7.397350 Gflop/s   B =    21.135285 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   8   L =   33554432   t = 3.407e-02 secs   P =     6.893586 Gflop/s   B =    19.695961 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =   9   L =   33554432   t = 3.335e-02 secs   P =     7.043563 Gflop/s   B =    20.124467 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  10   L =   33554432   t = 3.450e-02 secs   P =     6.808729 Gflop/s   B =    19.453510 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  11   L =   33554432   t = 3.238e-02 secs   P =     7.253735 Gflop/s   B =    20.724958 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  12   L =   33554432   t = 3.243e-02 secs   P =     7.242574 Gflop/s   B =    20.693068 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  13   L =   33554432   t = 3.218e-02 secs   P =     7.299224 Gflop/s   B =    20.854926 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  14   L =   33554432   t = 3.231e-02 secs   P =     7.270630 Gflop/s   B =    20.773230 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  15   L =   33554432   t = 3.303e-02 secs   P =     7.110799 Gflop/s   B =    20.316568 Gbytes/s
      VL =   4   nthr =  16   L =   33554432   t = 3.722e-02 secs   P =     6.309995 Gflop/s   B =    18.028556 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   1   L =   33554432   t = 5.573e-02 secs   P =     4.214636 Gflop/s   B =    12.041816 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   2   L =   33554432   t = 3.116e-02 secs   P =     7.537248 Gflop/s   B =    21.534995 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   3   L =   33554432   t = 2.498e-02 secs   P =     9.403648 Gflop/s   B =    26.867567 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   4   L =   33554432   t = 2.399e-02 secs   P =     9.790030 Gflop/s   B =    27.971515 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   5   L =   33554432   t = 2.668e-02 secs   P =     8.802318 Gflop/s   B =    25.149479 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   6   L =   33554432   t = 2.426e-02 secs   P =     9.680906 Gflop/s   B =    27.659732 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   7   L =   33554432   t = 2.376e-02 secs   P =     9.885770 Gflop/s   B =    28.245056 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   8   L =   33554432   t = 2.536e-02 secs   P =     9.260064 Gflop/s   B =    26.457324 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =   9   L =   33554432   t = 2.597e-02 secs   P =     9.045611 Gflop/s   B =    25.844602 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  10   L =   33554432   t = 2.625e-02 secs   P =     8.947335 Gflop/s   B =    25.563814 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  11   L =   33554432   t = 2.500e-02 secs   P =     9.395882 Gflop/s   B =    26.845376 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  12   L =   33554432   t = 2.518e-02 secs   P =     9.328337 Gflop/s   B =    26.652392 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  13   L =   33554432   t = 2.479e-02 secs   P =     9.476547 Gflop/s   B =    27.075849 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  14   L =   33554432   t = 2.496e-02 secs   P =     9.409747 Gflop/s   B =    26.884992 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  15   L =   33554432   t = 2.547e-02 secs   P =     9.223283 Gflop/s   B =    26.352238 Gbytes/s
      VL =   8   nthr =  16   L =   33554432   t = 2.829e-02 secs   P =     8.303835 Gflop/s   B =    23.725243 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   1   L =   33554432   t = 5.727e-02 secs   P =     4.101221 Gflop/s   B =    11.717773 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   2   L =   33554432   t = 3.135e-02 secs   P =     7.491573 Gflop/s   B =    21.404494 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   3   L =   33554432   t = 2.335e-02 secs   P =    10.058759 Gflop/s   B =    28.739312 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   4   L =   33554432   t = 2.089e-02 secs   P =    11.243631 Gflop/s   B =    32.124659 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   5   L =   33554432   t = 2.203e-02 secs   P =    10.662208 Gflop/s   B =    30.463451 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   6   L =   33554432   t = 2.008e-02 secs   P =    11.696502 Gflop/s   B =    33.418576 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   7   L =   33554432   t = 1.998e-02 secs   P =    11.754214 Gflop/s   B =    33.583469 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   8   L =   33554432   t = 2.108e-02 secs   P =    11.141491 Gflop/s   B =    31.832832 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =   9   L =   33554432   t = 2.247e-02 secs   P =    10.453722 Gflop/s   B =    29.867777 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  10   L =   33554432   t = 2.252e-02 secs   P =    10.431484 Gflop/s   B =    29.804241 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  11   L =   33554432   t = 2.117e-02 secs   P =    11.093447 Gflop/s   B =    31.695562 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  12   L =   33554432   t = 2.119e-02 secs   P =    11.084759 Gflop/s   B =    31.670741 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  13   L =   33554432   t = 2.084e-02 secs   P =    11.268896 Gflop/s   B =    32.196847 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  14   L =   33554432   t = 2.108e-02 secs   P =    11.144560 Gflop/s   B =    31.841601 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  15   L =   33554432   t = 2.143e-02 secs   P =    10.959766 Gflop/s   B =    31.313618 Gbytes/s
      VL =  16   nthr =  16   L =   33554432   t = 2.349e-02 secs   P =     9.998918 Gflop/s   B =    28.568338 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   1   L =   33554432   t = 5.784e-02 secs   P =     4.061192 Gflop/s   B =    11.603404 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   2   L =   33554432   t = 3.164e-02 secs   P =     7.423722 Gflop/s   B =    21.210634 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   3   L =   33554432   t = 2.358e-02 secs   P =     9.961892 Gflop/s   B =    28.462550 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   4   L =   33554432   t = 2.105e-02 secs   P =    11.155622 Gflop/s   B =    31.873204 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   5   L =   33554432   t = 2.215e-02 secs   P =    10.603440 Gflop/s   B =    30.295543 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   6   L =   33554432   t = 2.006e-02 secs   P =    11.709222 Gflop/s   B =    33.454920 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   7   L =   33554432   t = 2.003e-02 secs   P =    11.723916 Gflop/s   B =    33.496903 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   8   L =   33554432   t = 2.102e-02 secs   P =    11.176751 Gflop/s   B =    31.933574 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =   9   L =   33554432   t = 2.238e-02 secs   P =    10.493183 Gflop/s   B =    29.980522 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  10   L =   33554432   t = 2.250e-02 secs   P =    10.437463 Gflop/s   B =    29.821324 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  11   L =   33554432   t = 2.107e-02 secs   P =    11.147940 Gflop/s   B =    31.851257 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  12   L =   33554432   t = 2.111e-02 secs   P =    11.128453 Gflop/s   B =    31.795579 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  13   L =   33554432   t = 2.092e-02 secs   P =    11.228630 Gflop/s   B =    32.081801 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  14   L =   33554432   t = 2.086e-02 secs   P =    11.259417 Gflop/s   B =    32.169764 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  15   L =   33554432   t = 2.133e-02 secs   P =    11.010889 Gflop/s   B =    31.459683 Gbytes/s
      VL =  32   nthr =  16   L =   33554432   t = 2.391e-02 secs   P =     9.825537 Gflop/s   B =    28.072964 Gbytes/s
```

I need to use "VL", "nthr", and "B" variables to obtain a graph like this:

[image]

in Any cureves in the diagram, the value of "VL" is constant. I have also prepared a python code and it works but before using the code I have to split the data for each "VL" values in a separate file. Can we use a single data file and split it then plot the curves?

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

data_1 = np.loadtxt("1.txt", usecols = (19,5))
data_2 = np.loadtxt("2.txt", usecols = (19,5)) 
data_4 = np.loadtxt("4.txt", usecols = (19,5)) 
data_8 = np.loadtxt("8.txt", usecols = (19,5)) 
data_16 = np.loadtxt("16.txt", usecols = (19,5)) 
data_32 = np.loadtxt("32.txt", usecols = (19,5)) 
     
times_1 = data_1[:,0]
nproc_1 = data_1[:,1]
     
times_2 = data_2[:,0]
nproc_2 = data_2[:,1]
     
times_4 = data_4[:,0]
nproc_4 = data_4[:,1]
     
times_8 = data_8[:,0]
nproc_8 = data_8[:,1]
     
times_16 = data_16[:,0]
nproc_16 = data_16[:,1]
     
times_32 = data_32[:,0]
nproc_32 = data_32[:,1]
     
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.clf()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.plot(nproc_1, times_1, ls="-", color="r", marker="o", label="VL=1")
ax.plot(nproc_2, times_2, ls="-", color="b", marker="o", label="VL=2")
ax.plot(nproc_4, times_4, ls="-", color="g", marker="o", label="VL=4")
ax.plot(nproc_8, times_8, ls="-", color="c", marker="o", label="VL=8")
ax.plot(nproc_16, times_16, ls="-", color="m", marker="o", label="VL=16")
ax.plot(nproc_32, times_32, ls="-", color="k", marker="o", label="VL=32")

plt.legend()
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\beta_{IO}$' "[GBytes/s]")
ax.set_xlabel(r"$n_{OMP}$")
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.show()
fig.savefig("figure.pdf")
          
fig.patch.set_facecolor(None)
fig.patch.set_alpha(0)
fig.savefig("linalg.png", bbox_inches='tight',
facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), dpi=400)
```

Now I need to know how can I modify this code to a better one by doing less steps.

Is it possible to parse the data file in a such way, that it doesn't have to be initially split into separate VL files?

Comment: How are the `.txt` files you load formatted? Same as the data file sample you provided?

Comment: Exactly the same as here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could grab `VL` value from the text file:

```py
data = np.loadtxt("sample.txt", usecols = (19, 5, 2))
```

And then group it by it:

```py
data_grouped = np.split(data[:,:], np.unique(data[:, 2], return_index=True)[1][1:])
```

Then process the data as you did originally but in for loop:

```py
for item in data_grouped:
    times = item[:, 0]
    nproc = item[:, 1]
    vl = int(item[0, 2])

    # Do a plotting here based on vl value
```

To achieve different markers and lines per VL, you could map them in dictionary:

```py
styles = {
    1: {"ls": "-", "marker": "o", "color": "red", "label": "VL = 1"
    2: ...
}
```

and then access them using the `vl` variable

```py
ax.plot(
    nproc,
    times,
    ls=styles[vl]["ls"],
    color=styles[vl]["color"],
    marker=styles[vl]["marker"],
    label=styles[vl]["label"]
)
```